# Passing Parameters in VB Script

Tags: parameters, vbscript

I have written a small script as below:

```
Dim CMD
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
CMD = Wscript.Arguments(0)
WshShell.Run CMD
```

Now I want to call this script and pass a parameter as below:

```
I:\VbScript.vbs \\svaaoffprg2\ODrive\pros_groups\GRMS\GmLoad5.exe/f="\\Svaakntnas537\BODI\Data Files\ACC\PROS_LOAD\G5\Staging\VSGPNR120918.DAT"
```

Please can you advise how can I do this as this inverted commas in parameter call are causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Double-quoting shall work:

`I:\VbScript.vbs "\\svaaoffprg2\ODrive\pros_groups\GRMS\GmLoad5.exe/f="\\Svaakntnas537\BODI\Data Files\ACC\PROS_LOAD\G5\Staging\VSGPNR120918.DAT""`

Comment: Good answer, bad implementation. It should be: `I:\VbScript.vbs "\\svaaoffprg2\ODrive\pros_groups\GRMS\GmLoad5.exe/f=""\\Svaakntnas537\BODI\Data Files\ACC\PROS_LOAD\G5\Staging\VSGPNR120918.DAT"""`

Answer (score 0):

```
cscript.exe I:\VbScript.vbs "\\svaaoffprg2\ODrive\pros_groups\GRMS\GmLoad5.exe/f=\\Svaakntnas537\BODI\Data Files\ACC\PROS_LOAD\G5\Staging\VSGPNR120918.DAT"
```

cscript.exe I:\VbScript.vbs "\svaaoffprg2\ODrive\pros_groups\GRMS\GmLoad5.exe/f=", "\Svaakntnas537\BODI\Data Files\ACC\PROS_LOAD\G5\Staging\VSGPNR120918.DAT"

Try this it works for me.